# SQL IF / ELSE in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In MySQL,

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT mtrNo from tblMeter where mtrNo = '0000033')
    BEGIN
        insert into tblMeter (mtrNo) values ('0000033')
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        update tblMeter set Name = 'A-15' where mtrNo = '0000033'
    END
```

is work.

But in SQLite, two SQL statement is needed.

```
insert into tblMeter (mtrNo, Name) select '0000033', 'A-15' where not exists (SELECT mtrNo from tblMeter where mtrNo = '0000033')
update tblMeter set Name = 'A-15'  where mtrNo = '0000033' and exists (SELECT mtrNo from tblMeter where mtrNo = '0000033')
```

Can you make it into one SQL statement like MySQL?

I know insert or replace, but I can't use because table don't has unique key.

Comment: I don't think so, but reversing the order of your insert and update statements would be more "efficient" in the case that the record did not exist.  Right now it does the insert, then immediately updates the same row.  Reversed order would skip the update (if it doesn't exist) then do the insert.  (You asked a direct question that deserves an answer, but I can't help wonder why you either don't have a unique key and/or normalize the tables to avoid this conundrum.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `INSERT OR REPLACE` and the so-called UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`) statement rely on the failure of a unique or primary key constraint.  Although your own data does not have a unique constraint, sqlite provides one for you as an automatic integer `rowid` primary key.  You can use this to leverage the behavior of either alternative insert statement.

This first statement should reproduce the MySQL behavior exactly since it 1) does not assign a value to `Name` on the insert, and 2) it updates a single column of existing rows.  The fact that your table does not have a unique key indicates that it could have multiple rows with the same `mtrNo` values.  The complexity of the nested queries is to retrieve *all existing rows* and/or produce a valid `rowid` value for a new row:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblMeter AS ti
       (rowid, mtrNo)
       SELECT COALESCE(t1.rowid, (SELECT max(tx.rowid) FROM tblMeter AS tx) + 1, 1) AS rid,
              val.mtrNo
              FROM (SELECT '0000033' AS mtrNo) AS val
                   LEFT JOIN tblMeter AS t1
                   ON val.mtrNo == t1.mtrNo
              WHERE true --avoid parsing ambiguity
ON CONFLICT (rowid)
DO UPDATE SET Name = 'A-15'; --Only rows with matching mtrNo will be updated
```

---

Since you mentioned the `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement, here is a working version of that.  However, it is not the same thing since it completely replaces existing rows rather than just updating them.  This differentiation is crucial especially if your table has more columns than referenced in the sample code.  This statement will delete existing data!

Not only that, but unlike the MySQL code, this inserts a value into the `Name` column for the new row.  A few more nested subqueries could perhaps resolve this difference, but it is overly complicated when the UPSERT statement already satisfies your question more precisely.

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tblMeter
       (rowid, mtrNo, Name)
       SELECT COALESCE(t1.rowid, (SELECT max(tx.rowid) FROM tblMeter AS tx) + 1, 1) AS rid,
              val.mtrNo,
              val.Name
              FROM (SELECT '0000033' AS mtrNo, 'A-15' AS Name) AS val
                   LEFT JOIN tblMeter AS t1
                   ON val.mtrNo == t1.mtrNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have a sufficiently recent version of SQLite, you can use the so-called "UPSERT" construct:

> UPSERT in SQLite follows the syntax established by PostgreSQL.
>
> UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04)

Note that there is no `UPSERT` keyword.

For details, see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html